# JTable has size limitations?

Tags: java, swing, defaulttablemodel

the table only displays 3083 line while in mysql are more than that !

        `DefaultTableModel modelEtud = new DefaultTableModel(null, new String[]{"N°", "C.I.N. / N° inscription", "Nom Fr", "Prenon Fr", "Matière", "Nombre Absences", "Groupe"}) {
    };
    String requetEtud = "SELECT * FROM etudiant2sga WHERE id = '" + resultatAbs.getString("idEtudiant") + "' AND idGroupe = '" + idGroupe + "' LIMIT 0 , 10000";
     try {
 ResultSet resultat = stmtSelectEtudiant.executeQuery(requetEtud);
        while (resultat.next()) {
            modelEtud.addRow(new Object[]{N, resultat.getString("id"), resultat.getString("nomFr"), resultat.getString("prenomFr"), EE, new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(resultatAbs.getDate("dateAbs")), "séance " + resultatAbs.getInt("seance"), jTableGpr.getValueAt(row, 2)});
        }
    }`

even with this code the problem is not solved:

```
modelEtud.setRowCount(10000);
```

Comment: how long is the array you pass to the table model? How do you load the table?

Comment: The problem is with your code not the table. The setRowCount() method won' t do anything. It just adds rows of empty data. You still need to read the data from your database to populate the model. See the [Table From Database Example](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) found in the `Get The Code` section for a generic working example to get you started.

Comment: please see new code(edit)